# How to notify my IP to other devices in my network

Tags: windows, networking, ip, ping, arp

I have a setup with a few Linux devices and one windows device connected to a switch. I would like a way to tell the windows machine which IPs the Linux machines get when booting. I have tried to populate the arp table on the windows machine by pinging broadcast but I have not succeeded because windows doesn't reply to broadcast.

I have tried also nmap but that is not an option because it takes really long to scan (the net mask is **255.255.0.0**)

Comment: Even if you manage to populate your ARP tables with all the other network hosts, the ARP table entries will time out. You should just let ARP do what it is designed to do and populate the table when it is necessary.

Comment: I understand your point. But this is a setup to demo a project so I just need something that works :-) I need the windows machine to find out the ip of the linux devices with a fast script. Otherwise I would need to log in to each Linux machine via serial to find out its ip and start the demo...

Comment: It sounds like you should be using DNS, DHCP reservations, or static addressing.

Comment: The problem is that I have no control over the switch that will be there. I have tested several models and everyone has different network addresses and network masks

Comment: Then write an application that uses multicast to discover all your hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a static IP and other network settings on all the Linux machines.
then on your Windows system edit your HOST file with the names and ip addresses. 
This should bypass the need for a DHCP or DNS. 
However other systems on the network will not be able to find your systems.

Regardless you still need to speak to the guys who administer the network to add your linux systems in. 
It is rather impolite and/or against policy and somewhat bordering on illegal; to simply plug in your systems into the network not owned by yourself.

So if you have a right or need, the administrators will listen and should help you.